# Python iterate over two lists simultaneously

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, foreach, iteration

Is there a way in python to forloop over two or more lists simultaneously?

Something like

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
for x,y in a,b:
    print x,y
```

to output

```
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

I know that I can do it with tuples like

```
l = [(1,4), (2,5), (3,6)]
for x,y in l:
    print x,y
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use the [`zip()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to pair up lists:

```
for x, y in zip(a, b):
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [4,5,6]
>>> for x, y in zip(a, b):
...     print x, y
... 
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

Comment: @ilamengl: if you are going to alter answers from Python 2 to Python 3 syntax or documentation references, then do so for the question as well. Since this question is tagged, explicitly, with the `python-2.7` tag I'm reverting your edit, as it is *not applicable here*.

Comment: Python 2 support has ended, yes, but that doesn't mean that there is no one still using it. Always check the tags when reading answers, please do not change tags.