# How do I combine two lists into one, while changing some of the values?

Tags: python, list

I am working on my very first coding project, which is to make a text encoder. Once complete, I plan to make the decoder that will pair with it. For now, I am having trouble getting two lists to combine/overlap. I apologize if what I am about to show has an actual name that references it, I am new to coding and still learning many things.

```
list1 = [20.0, 'X', 'X', 46.0, 0.0, 18.0, 'X', 40.0]
list2 = ['Y', 31.0, 45.0, 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 47.0, 'Y']
```

I need the output to be:

```
list3 = [20.0, 31.0, 45.0, 46.0, 0.0, 18.0, 47.0, 40.0]
```

Both lists have an equal number of values, and I need to combine them into one list, keep the numbers in their current order, and eliminate the "X"s and "Y"s entirely.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Comment: Here is one way to iterate over the two lists simultaneously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21098350/python-iterate-over-two-lists-simultaneously?lq=1. You can use isintance(s, str) to test if s is a string. You can use list3.append(x) to append x to list3. Combine those and you will have a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use `zip` with `isinstance` in a list-comprehension:

```
list1 = [20.0, 'X', 'X', 46.0, 0.0, 18.0, 'X', 40.0]
list2 = ['Y', 31.0, 45.0, 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 47.0, 'Y']

list3 = [x if isinstance(x, float) else y for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
# [20.0, 31.0, 45.0, 46.0, 0.0, 18.0, 47.0, 40.0]
```

Comment: Comprehension expressions, `zip` and `isinntance` are too advanced for a complete beginner. Simple loops and an accumulator are more appropriate.

Comment: @Xero I have a little bit of familiarity with `zip`, even though I am still learning all of the different ways to implement it. but this is the first I am hearing of `isinstance`.

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [20.0, 'X', 'X', 46.0, 0.0, 18.0, 'X', 40.0]
list2 = ['Y', 31.0, 45.0, 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 47.0, 'Y']

list3 = []

for x in range(len(list1)):
    if isinstance(list1[x], float):
        list3.append(list1[x])

    else:
        list3.append(list2[x])

print(list3)
```

**OUTPUT:-**

```
[20.0, 31.0, 45.0, 46.0, 0.0, 18.0, 47.0, 40.0]
```

Comment: @jarmod can you please tell me why?

Comment: Your answer works, but is unpythonic. See https://python-forum.io/Thread-Basic-Never-use-for-i-in-range-len-sequence

Comment: @jarmod Thanks for your suggestion. I would look forward to do as you mentioned in the later future.

Answer (score 1):

As @Austin said use `zip` to combine several lists of the same size.

Here is a version a little easier to understand if your new to development

```
def get_number(item1, item2):
    if item1 in ['X', 'Y']:
        return item2
    else:
        return item1

[get_number(x, y) for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
```

**OUTPUT:-**

```
[20.0, 31.0, 45.0, 46.0, 0.0, 18.0, 47.0, 40.0]
```

Comment: True we shouldn't be hardcoding values but in this case the problem is not clear. The problem says we need to eliminate Xs and Ys, it doesn't really states that it should be float values. So what happens if is really an `int` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Why not `max` with `isinstance`:

```
print([max(i, key=lambda x: isinstance(x, float)) for i in zip(list1, list2)])
```

Output:

```
[20.0, 31.0, 45.0, 46.0, 0.0, 18.0, 47.0, 40.0]
```

Comment: This is not an obfuscation competition ;-) We're trying to teach basic Python to a beginner.

Answer (score -2):

```
list3 = [x if not str(x).isalpha() else list2[i] for i, x in enumerate(list1)]
```

verified

Comment: Er, no. Did you test this?

Comment: Your code results in the list [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].

Comment: sorry for previous answer... I edited code and it works

Answer (score -2):

This is a suggestion if you don't seriously care about the order of comnbined list

```py
list1 = [20.0, 'X', 'X', 46.0, 0.0, 18.0, 'X', 40.0]
list2 = ['Y', 31.0, 45.0, 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 47.0, 'Y']
a = list1 + list2
a = [x for x in a if not isinstance(x, str)]
```

```py
>>>a
[20.0, 46.0, 0.0, 18.0, 40.0, 31.0, 45.0, 47.0]
```

Comment: It does not output in the expected form.

Comment: @Austin, you mean the order of list?

Comment: That's not what the OP asked for. The output should be [20.0, 31.0, 45.0, 46.0, 0.0, 18.0, 47.0, 40.0].

Comment: @Austin, thanks for reminding. I edited my answer as a suggestion.