# How two write two nested lists column wise in .txt file?

Tags: python, nested-lists, txt

I have two list of lists looks like:

```
sentences = [['its', 'a', 'great', 'show'], ['nice', 'movie'], ['good', 'series']]
labels = [['O', 'O', 'O', 'B_A'], ['O', 'B_A'], ['O', 'B_A']]
```

I want to save these pair of lists **column wise** in **txt** file so each element pair should be separated by a white space, and each list pair should be separated by an empty line.

The desired output should be like:

```
its O
a O
great O
show B_A

nice O
movie B_A

good O
series B_A
```

I have tried this:

```
filename = 'data.txt'

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    for sen in sentences:
        for lab in labels:
            line = sen + ' ' + lab
            f.write(line)
```

I have the following error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

**Update**: Using the first answer, I am trying to define a function which takes two nested lists and the new file name as follows:

```
def create_txt(ls1, ls2,file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
        for sen, lab in zip(ls1,ls2):
            for i, j in zip(sen, lab):
                f.write(f'{i} {j}')
            f.write('\n')
    return file_name
```

But it returns the provided file name as a string:

```
create_txt(sentences, labels,'data_n.txt')

Output: 'data_n.txt'
```

what is the logical problem I've done here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python iterate over two lists simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21098350/python-iterate-over-two-lists-simultaneously)

Comment: Error is pretty self-explanatory. You're concatting lists to strings. You'll need to iterate the two main lists together using `zip`, then iterate sublists together using `zip` again, printing the pairs and printing your newline when the sublist iteration ends. Writing to file is irrelevant; if you can print, you can replace that with `f.write(string)`

Comment: @ggorlen I am trying with it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `csv` module for this.

```
import csv

with open("file.txt", "w", newline="\n") as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=" ")
    for sentence, label in zip(sentences, labels):
        for i, j in zip(sentence, label):
            writer.writerow([i, j])
        fp.write('\n')
```

without using any additional modules

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as fp:
    for sentence, label in zip(sentences, labels):
        for i, j in zip(sentence, label):
            fp.write(f'{i} {j}\n')
        fp.write('\n')
```

Comment: Thank you I tried it, but the sentences are still not separated by new line.

Comment: @AliF try it now.

Comment: Why would you need the `csv` module for this?  You should be able to just write out to a file without any additional imports.

Comment: @Snackhole you're right. added the solution without the use of `csv` module also.

Answer (score 1):

Another working answer, slightly different, with some explanatory comments:

```
sentences = [['its', 'a', 'great', 'show'], ['nice', 'movie'], ['good', 'series']]
labels = [['O', 'O', 'O', 'B_A'], ['O', 'B_A'], ['O', 'B_A']]

filename = "data.txt"
outputstring = ""

# Construct the output string with zip.

# First we're zipping the elements of the source lists,
# which gives a sequence of pairs like this:
# (sentences[0], labels[0]), (sentences[1], labels[1]), etc.

# Then we iterate over that sequence and zip up the contents of
# each pair of lists in the same way, and concatenate those strings
# with the outputstring, followed by a single newline character.
# After that, an extra newline is added to break up the groups.

for sentence, label in zip(sentences, labels):
    for i, j in zip(sentence, label):
        outputstring += i + " " + j + "\n"
    outputstring += "\n"

# This removes the extra whitespace at the end.

outputstring = outputstring.rstrip()

# Finally, you can just write the string to your output file.

with open(filename, "w") as f:
    f.write(outputstring)
```

And here is a second example without using `zip`:

```
sentences = [['its', 'a', 'great', 'show'], ['nice', 'movie'], ['good', 'series']]
labels = [['O', 'O', 'O', 'B_A'], ['O', 'B_A'], ['O', 'B_A']]

filename = "data.txt"
outputstring = ""

# Check the length of each list of lists and make sure they're the same:

sentenceslen = len(sentences)
labelslen = len(labels)

if sentenceslen != labelslen:
    print("Malformed data!")
    raise SystemExit

# Iterate over both lists using their lengths to define the range of indices.

for i in range(sentenceslen):
    
    # Check the lengths of each pair of sublists and make sure they're the same:
    
    subsentenceslen = len(sentences[i])
    sublabelslen = len(labels[i])
    
    if subsentenceslen != sublabelslen:
        print("Malformed data!")
        raise SystemExit
    
    # Iterate over each pair of sublists using their lengths to define the range of indices:
    
    for j in range(subsentenceslen):
        
        # Construct the outputstring by using both indices to drill down to the right strings,
        # ending with newline:
        
        outputstring += sentences[i][j] + " " + labels[i][j] + "\n"
    
    # Break up groups with newline again:
    
    outputstring += "\n"

# Remove whitespace at end:

outputstring = outputstring.rstrip()

# Write outputstring to file:

with open(filename, "w") as f:
    f.write(outputstring)
```

I do not recommend actually using the code in the second example.  It is unnecessarily complicated, but I include it for completeness and to illustrate how the use of the `zip` function above saves effort.  The `zip` function also does not care if you feed it lists of different length, so your script won't crash if you try that but don't check for it; it'll spit out pairs of values up to the length of the smaller list, and ignore values after that for the larger list.

Comment: Thank you for an amazing explanation! I am thinking about convert the first code to a function that takes two nested lists and the name of new txt file. Could I implement them using a function? Or that is not possible due to using ```with open(filename, 'w') as f: ...```?

Comment: Yep, should work fine.  Nothing special about handling files in functions!